# How can I implement built in signals, for my app?

Tags: django

I have a project myappointments, with two apps- appointments and clinic in it.

Objective: 
When a user logins, details should be entered in the database.

appointments/models.py:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    type=models.CharField(max_length=60)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

appointments/**init**.py:

```
default_app_config = 'appointments.apps.AppointmentsConfig'
```

appointments/apps.py:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
class AppointmentsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'appointments'
    def ready(self):
        import appointments.signals
```

appointments/signals.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in
from django.dispatch import receiver
def record_loggedin(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
  ev = Event(type="Login", description = 'User logged in: {}'.format(request.user.id))
  ev.save()
  print("User has logged in. Saved event to DB.")
user_logged_in.connect(record_loggedin)
```

What other modifications do I need to do this?

Comment: But what is the problem? It looks fairly correct.

Comment: The database isnt being updated. Neither is that print line being executed.

Comment: Yeah I agree, this looks like it should work, have you tested to see if your signal is being ready by Django at all? Like say, making a bad import and seeing if it throws an error.

Comment: @onyeka The problem is that the development server catches any errors there.

Comment: @Droidzone I don't understand... you're not using the dev server? So you're saying it works locally bit not on production?